# Keep width of container that of the longest child

Tags: javascript, html, css

In short: When I have a container and some inline-block divs, the container's width shrinks around the divs. But when the divs are too-long and therefore one of them goes to another line, the container width is rendered as 100%.

In the picture the default behavior is the first one, whereas the desired behavior is the second one.

[image]

Here is a fiddle with the example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gzbx4upq/

```
See fiddle for desired results
```

Comment: Provide some code, best a fiddle, not images

Comment: Please post your code within the question body. Don't break the rules by wrapping nonsense in code tags just to bypass the *JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code* warning.

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
display:block;
```

or

```
display:inline;
```

or

```
max-width:250px ;
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems possible using pseudo classes.

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
div:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    background-color: blue;
    z-index:-1;
}
div:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gzbx4upq/4/)**